# Как создавать превью статьи на сайте?

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать автоматическую генерацию изображения превью (для og:image) статьи пользователя на сайте?
Как это например реализовано у Habr. Когда делишься ссылкой на статью, то превью этой ссылки включает в себя шаблон, в который подставляется название статьи.
Не очень ясен алгоритм реализации. Первое, что приходит в голову, это генерация изображения и сохранение его в каталог как отдельное изображение и потом просто подтягивать, но возможно, есть какие-то иные способы для генерации "на лету"?
Пробовал искать в интернете, но почему-то именно того, о чём я говорю, ничего не нашёл. Возможно вопрос не правильно формулирую, но надеюсь, что здесь мне подскажут.
Заранее, большое спасибо!

Comment: Можно и на лету: для этого нужно чтобы веб-сервер знал, что обращение к картинке — это обращение к скрипту на бэкенде (через .htaccess или конфиг nginx), который будет генерировать картинку и не сохранять её в файл, а отдавать потоком. Но лучше, всё же, в методе, который сохраняет статью генерировать картинку и класть, условно, в папку, тк генерация на лету при каждом обращении — довольно дорогая операция для сервера.

Comment: храните эти ваши og:image в отдельной папке. реврайтами настройкте, что если файла нет, то управление передавайте в пхп, который изображение это генерит и сохраняет в эту самую папку.  При изменении (заголовка) статьи удаляйте файл. Также можно удалять старые какие-то, чтобы места не занимали.